# How can client exit while using fork in jsonrpc-c server

Tags: c, linux, sockets, json-rpc, libev

I am using jsonrpc-c to write a [remote shell toy](https://github.com/hmng/jsonrpc-c/tree/master).

The client side uses `nc` to send request to server:

```
echo "{\"method\":\"sayHello\"}" | nc localhost 1234
```

The code of the server is simple:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h> 
#include "jsonrpc-c.h"
#define DEFAULT_PORT            1234  //the port users will be connecting to

static struct jrpc_server my_server;


cJSON * hello(jrpc_context * ctx, cJSON * params, cJSON *id) {
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid==0)
  {
    freopen( "/dev/null", "w", stdout );
    freopen( "/dev/null", "r", stdin ); 
    signal(SIGCHLD,SIG_IGN);
    while(true){
    printf("hello in child\n");
    }
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("hello in father\n");
    return cJSON_CreateString("done");
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int port;
    if (argc == 2) 
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
    else 
        port = DEFAULT_PORT;

    jrpc_server_init(&my_server, (int)port);

    jrpc_register_procedure(&my_server, hello, "sayHello", NULL);

    jrpc_server_run(&my_server);
    jrpc_server_destroy(&my_server);
}
```

When executing `echo "{\"method\":\"sayHello\"}" | nc localhost 1234`, the client blocks forever.
Are there any methods to let the client exit when the server's parent process returns, while allowing the server's child process to continue running?

Comment: "when the server's parent process returns," With that `while(true)` I won't expect the server to return at all.

Comment: @Gerhardh "I don't quite understand why the server cannot return. Isn't 'while true' only executed in the child process? The parent process forked should still continue to execute the return?"

Comment: Two things: `nc` is used as client. The wording is a bit bad, because its call and the client seem to be different things. Further, you say "server's parent process returns", you mean specifically the call to `hello()`, right? It could be misunderstood as the whole server process terminating. Lastly, what if you don't use `fork()`? Does the client then terminate? I don't see a reason why the client should terminate if the server doesn't close the connection and I'm not sure wether it's not left open by default.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for the correction. I expected that the connection will be closed after the parent process of hello returns. So, it seems impossible to run a background process in hello() (what I actually want to do is launching a background process by using fork() and execl() when client calls the hello() )

Comment: Curiosity got me, so I looked at the code. In https://github.com/hmng/jsonrpc-c/blob/master/src/jsonrpc-c.c, take a look at the cases where `close_connection()` is called. Those are only error cases! If you processed one request, it just keeps sitting there waiting for the next request. Actually, try passing `-N` to `nc`. Man page says "shutdown(2) the network socket after EOF on the input.  Some servers require this to finish their work." ;) BTW: That should not depend on whether you fork or not, which was exactly why I asked. That's also the reason SO requires a [mcve]!